# Where is wsimport after Java 11

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsimport, java-metro-framework

I've used wsimport and other Metro tools for many years but since the removal of Java EE modules from Java 11, I can't find the tools.

Where can I find the `wsimport` executable?

Comment: Looks like it's been removed in JDK11 [This might give you some tips](https://github.com/javaee/metro-jax-ws/issues/1251)

Comment: The [Java EE SDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) still has it.

Comment: It does?  Nice, thanks for pointing that out @VGR !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The executables for WSIMPORT can be found at the main site https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/.

They're no longer part of JDK.

Comment: When I run the wsimport.sh script, it fails with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.api.ErrorListener. Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen you opened an issue for that =) let us wait

Comment: For future reference, the updated versions are downloadable from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-ri/