# How to correctly install wsimport

Tags: soap, wsimport

Ich wrote a wsdl for a Webservice, which is in a folder named xml. Now I want to generate the JAVA-classes with the following command:

wsimport -Xnocompile -s src xml/GuestBook.wsdl

As my eclipse doesn't ship wsimport, I downloaded jaxws-ri and set its path (C:\Users...\jaxws-ri\bin under system variables), and I also restarted the computer.

Haplessly, I cannot generate the Java classes because wsimport semms not to work. What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

> ...wsimport semms not to work...

You didn't say what is the error. But you can try an updated version of the jaxws-ri executables, [see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192401/where-is-wsimport-after-jdk11/53251877?noredirect=1#comment107433070_53251877).

Comment: I finally succeeded with using wsimport by simply downgrading my JDK.